# Magento2: Show price on bundle option summary

Tags: magento2, bundled-product

I want to show selected bundle options price in the summary block at right. By default, it only shows the selected option from the bundle product. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I managed to add price of selected action when page loads. Code is as below in app\code\Magento\Bundle\view\frontend\web\js\product-summary.js:

_price_: this.cache.currentElement.options[key].selections[row].prices.finalPrice.amount. But, when I select one more option its showing js error like this: http://prntscr.com/d5foz9. Also, the price is not showing the currency symbol. Please see this http://prnt.sc/d5fpy6. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Able to add total summary for individual item selected on bundle product summary. Also, added currency symbol before price.
Here is the solution https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7374#issuecomment-259978358

Comment: Is there a way to display product image in bundle option summary?